# Nobel Prize for Applied Mathematics

Tags: mathematics, nobel-prize

There is no Nobel Prize for mathematics. However, have there been any Nobel Prizes for the use of applied mathematics to model the real world?

Comment: Yes, for example google for "John Nash". (Subjective opinion: Nobel prize for economics is effectively a Nobel prize for math.)

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica For his work in game theory? It's very interesting stuff. Do you know of any recent journal articles that have been published using his Nobel Prize awarded work? I would enjoy having a read.

Comment: Maybe any Nobel prize for physics can be considered as prize for applied mathematics.

Comment: The 1979 prize in Physiology or Medicine,  awarded for the development of the CAT scanner, should count as applied mathematics, too.

Comment: There is no such designation as "applied mathematics" in Nobel prizes. But many prizes for physics, chemistry and economy were really awarded for "applied mathemtics" with applications to physics, chemistry and economy.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Such as John Nash and his Nobel Prize for economics in 1994?

Comment: M B: Yes, but this is only one example. Kantorovich also received a Nober prize in economics, and the list of physicists and chemists who received it for mathematics is too long to insert here.

Comment: @MB It is not an ivory tower result about an abstract thing. For example, it explains, why any Big Company is a network of totally incompetent a...s, and why can they still remain on the top.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Reading Nash's 1951 paper, there's not a whole lot of mathematics in it.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica The pseudo-Nobel Economics award wasn't even created until 1968, and many in the fields of science don't consider it to be a scientific award.

Comment: You may be confusing  "applying mathematics to study XXXX"  with  the **field** of Applied Mathematics.  They are only partially overlapping.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a list of "Mathematicians who were awarded Nobel prize" taken from
[this paper](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_04_04.html)

1902 Lorentz (Physics)

1904 Rayleigh (Physics)

1911 Wien (Physics)

1918 Planck (Physics)

1921 Einstein (Physics)

1922 Bohr (Physics)

1929 de Broglie (Physics)

1932 Heisenberg (Physics)

1933 Schroedinger (Physics)

1933 Dirac (Physics)

1945 Pauli (Physics)

1950 Russell (Literature)

1954 Born (Physics)

1962 Landau (Physics)

1963 Wigner (Physics)

1965 Schwinger (Physics)

1965 Feynman (Physics)

1969 Tinbergen (Economics)

1975 Kantorovich (Economics)

1983 Chandrasekhar (Physics)

1994 Selten (Economics)

1994 Nash (Economics)

The work of all of them, except Russell qualifies as "applied mathematics".

Comment: I don't agree that "using math to solve a problem" is equivalent to "the field of Applied Mathematics"

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: then give your definition of "applied mathematics". The work of the listed people is not just "using math", but "developing new math to solve a specific problem of science". And this is my definition of applied math.

Comment: For example, Lorenz group was NOT studied by mathematicians before Lorenz, as a pure mathematical object. Same applies to "Feynman integrals".

Comment: Well,  at many Universities there's a separate Department Of Applied Mathematics which exists conceptually between Mathematics and  Engineering departments.

Comment: The views at various universities on what their department of applied mathematics is supposed to do differ. For example, in many US universities, they do not qualify mathematical physics as applied mathematics. I use a broader (and more consistent) definition of applied mathematics.

Comment: They also have separate statistics departments. Is not this also applied mathematics?

Comment: No,  statistics is not applied math.   Statistics theorems can be applied to realworld situations, but the math is "pure."

Comment: I strongly agree with Alexandre Eremenko's notion of "applied math". In particular, the idea that the politics of academic departments is a meaningful indicator of scientific or intellectual connections is pretty funny. And, for that matter, if I (and other people) apply ideas that arose in physics to number theory, is that "applied physics"? And automorphic forms in string theory is "applied math". And "pure" as opposed to "realworld"? A supposed distinction very hard to understand, and all the more difficult the more I learn...

Comment: @Carl Witthof: really? Who would care to state and prove those theorems in statistics if not applications to the "real world"? It seems that you confuse Probability and Statistics.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Interesting answer. Unfortunately, the link doesn't appear to work anymore

Comment: @Max Muller: You are right: it does not work anymore. Unfortunately I do not remember the coordinates of the article. The author is Keith Devlin.

Answer (score 2):

Merton and Scholes received the 1997 Nobel prize in Economics for the famous Black–Scholes–Merton model, which is a mathematical model for the dynamics of a financial market containing derivative investment instruments and the foundation of mathematical finance.